# OpenGL blend two FBOs

Tags: opengl, fbo, blending

In a game I'm writing, I have a level, which is properly rendered to the on-screen render buffer provided to me by the OS. I can also render this to a framebuffer, then render this framebuffer onto the output render buffer.

To add a background, I want to render a different scene, an effect, or whatever to a second framebuffer, then have this "show through" wherever the framebuffer containing the level has no pixel set, i.e. the alpha value is 0. I think this is called alpha blending.

How would I go about doing this with OpenGL? I think `glBlendFunc` could be used to achieve this, but I am not sure how I can couple this with the framebuffer drawing routines to properly achieve the result I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`glBlendFunc` allows the application to blend (merge) the output of all your current draw operations (say, X) with the current "display" framebuffer (say, Y) that already exists.

ie,

New display output = X (blend) Y

You can control the *blend* function by gl as below snippet shows for example:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Full usage shown here

https://github.com/prabindh/sgxperf/blob/master/sgxperf_test4.cpp

Note that the concepts of "showing through" and "blending" are a little different, you might just want to stick with "per pixel alpha blending" terminology.

Comment: This makes sense — I presume I would first draw my background in the destination framebuffer, set this as the destination buffer, then set my foreground as the read buffer and do a blitting operation with blend modes set?

Comment: @TristanSeifert bitting is not suitable here. It's a different operation than blending.

Answer (score 0):

FBOs are just a containers and are not storage. What you need to do is attach a texture target for each FBO and render your output to that texture, once you have done this. You can use your output textures on a fullscreen quad and do whatever you want with your blending.